# Swift enums, set the value to the name of the item?

Tags: swift

I'm parsing strings from a file. One of the strings has the same value as the names in an enum of colors. For instance, the enum contains `Purple` and one of the strings might be `"Purple"`. I know there's a way to select an enum item based on its value using `rawValue` (et al), but is there something similar for the *name*? Here is the enum...

```
enum Colors: Int {
 case White = 0
 case Red
 case Orange
 case Yellow
 case Green
 case Cyan
 case Blue
 case Purple
}
```

Comment: No there isn't. Why don't you _give_ your enum string raw values? That is exactly what they are _for_!

Comment: Do you have some other really good reason for using an Int raw value instead of a String raw value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll play along with the idea that your enum has Int raw values but now you want to look up cases by way of a string. (If you knew you wanted to look up cases by string, it's a little hard to see why you didn't give your enum String raw values to start with. But, as I say, I'll play along, just for the fun of it.)

So... Remember that an enum is an object type like any other. Thus you can give it a custom method!

So you can have a method where you start with an array of strings, e.g. `["White", "Red", "Orange"...]`, look up the string using `find`, thus giving you an index number, and use that index number as the raw value to reach the desired case.

```
enum Colors: Int {
    case White = 0
    case Red
    case Orange
    case Yellow
    case Green
    case Cyan
    case Blue
    case Purple
    static func byString(s:String) -> Colors? {
        let arr = ["White", "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Cyan", "Blue", "Purple"]
        let ix = find(arr, s)
        if ix == nil {
            return nil
        }
        return Colors(rawValue:ix!)
    }
}
```

So now you can say stuff like this:

```
let c = Colors.byString("Red")
```

Comment: That is *precisely* the sort of thing I was looking for. Why? I know I could have done this with a case statement, but I want to *learn swift* and this is exactly the sort of thing I was wondering about. A function in a enum? I need to know this stuff!

Comment: Lots of examples in my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_enum_methods

Comment: It would look a bit Swiftier with optional binding: `if let ix = find(arr, s) { ...`. – Sorry for telling you what you already know :) – Or perhaps `return Colors(rawValue: find(arr, s) ?? -1)`